# Understanding Energy Function

Tags: interpolation, mesh

I am trying to implement as rigid as possible mesh interpolation solution provided in this article called "As-Rigid-As-Possible Surface Morphing"

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.228.4957&rep=rep1&type=pdf

I understand how to find transformation matrices and translation vectors for each triangle(section 3.1) and how to interpolate them for a given time t in 0 and 1 interval (section 3.2). The part I do not understand is the equation 11(section 3.3) in the article. I know how to obtain every variable for equation 11 but I am confused and do not know how to solve energy function to minimize interpolated vertex positions. I appreciate any explanation.

Comment: How does this relate to *Mathematica* the software produced by Wolfram Research?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster. Answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy is quadratic in its constituents and if I got it right, the constituents are linear in the vertex positions of the new mesh. So the energy is a quadratic function in the vertex positions of the new mesh. Minimization of a quadratic function $$F(x) = \frac{1}{2} \langle x , A \, x -b \rangle + c$$ boils down to solving a linear equation $$A \,x = b.$$ Quite likely, $A$ is a sparse, positive definite matrix and can be assembled by transversing the triangle list of the mesh. As usual in computer graphics, the equation is then solved by a direct solver; for example by LU-factorization or Cholesky factorization.

Comment: Thanks Henrik, in this sparse A matrix, where should I place my interpolated transformation matrix and translation vector information for each vertex? I am lost at this point. So I assume x is the variable vector and b will be the final vertex coordinates I guess?

Comment: No, it is not that simple. Have a look at paper [5] by Alexa, Cohen-Or, and Levin; maybe you find these details there (or in any other of the cited papers).

Comment: Got it, thank you for your time and response :)

Comment: You're welcome.